# How can I handle exceptions in Web API 1.0 at my BaseAPIController

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api

I am currently using Web API 1.0 and .NET 4.0
I need a function  that can take care of the noise of catching and handling exceptions in my Base API so that I dont need to write that in every RESTful operation.

```
 public int Get(WelcomeTeamNotes note)
    {

        try
        {
            return _customerService.UpdateNotes(note);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error("CustomerController : _customerService.UpdateNotes(note)", ex);
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
    }
```

Using Log4net to log the error. I have seen such implementation in Web API 2.0 but not getting one for 1.0 implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you probably should use an exception filter.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
    public sealed class ExceptionHandlerAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
        {
            base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);

            var e = actionExecutedContext.Exception;
            if (e != null)
            {
                // do whatever you need with your exception
            }

        }
```

You may place this attribute on some of your controllers or register at global configuration to cover them all at once.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new ExceptionHandlerAttribute());

    ...
}
```